# Understanding addSubview: memoryLeak

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

I don't really understand, why this code leaks.

```
ParentViewController *parentController = [[ParentViewController alloc] init];
ChildViewController *childController = [[ChildViewController alloc] init];
[parentController containerAddChildViewController:childController];
[[self window] setRootViewController:parentController];

- (void)containerAddChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childViewController {
    [self addChildViewController:childViewController];
    [self.view addSubview:childViewController.view]; // Instruments is telling me, the leak occurs here!
    [childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

According to Instruments, this line: `[self.view addSubview:childViewController.view];` is leaking. The whole code is called **once** in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, but it is shown that this code is responsible for 30 leaks (approx. 1.12 kB).

Comment: Calling `addChildViewController` will result in the new child view controller's view being added to the parent view controller's hierarchy, so it's rarely appropriate to use it in conjunction with `addSubview`  Especially when you're adding the view to a different view hierarchy completely.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I'am adding a viewController to another viewController. `addChildViewController` on it's own doesn't add the `view` to the `parentViewController`. I'am using the way described by Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html).

Comment: There is no leak in the code you've shown us. There may be a leak inside the view construction of ChildViewController's or ParentViewController's view. Check the viewDidLoad of either of those.

Comment: I've commented the whole code in both viewControllers out, and it still show leaks.